# mithril.js stuck in loop calling controller

Tags: mithril.js

I'm trying to POST a token and display the results as an ordered list.  I would like the list to update onchange of the input.  On page load the request POST is infinitely looping with error:

```
TypeError: ctrl.keys(...) is undefined
```

I suspect that my assumptions of how the data binding on the controller works are completely wrong.

```js
//component
var tISM = {};


//model
tISM = { 
 Key: function(data) {
  this.Id = m.prop(data.Id);
  this.Name = m.prop(data.Name);
  this.CreationTime = m.prop(data.CreationTime);
 },

 keys:  function(token) {
  return m.request({
   method: "POST",
          url: "key/list",
   data: { "token": token },
   type: tISM.Key
  })
 },
};

//controller
tISM.controller = function() {
 // when this controller is updated perform a new POST for data by calling message?
 var token = m.prop("xxx")

 var keys = function() {
  tISM.keys(this.token)
 }
 return { token, keys }
};

//view
tISM.view = function(ctrl) {
 return m("div"), [
  m("ol", ctrl.keys().map( function(key, index) {
   return m("li", key.Id, key.Name, key.CreationTime)
  })),
  m("input", {
   onchange: m.withAttr("value", ctrl.token)
  })
 ]
};



//initialize
m.mount(document.getElementById("app"), tISM);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mithril/0.2.5/mithril.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Mithril App</title>
    <script src="mithril.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was I don't know javascript.  This works:

```js
//component
var tISM = {};

//model
tISM.Key = function(data) {
 this.Id = m.prop(data.Id);
 this.Name = m.prop(data.Name);
 this.CreationTime = m.prop(data.CreationTime);
}
tISM = { 

 keys:  function(token) {
  return m.request({
   method: "POST",
          url: "key/list",
   data: { "token": token },
   type: tISM.Key
  })
 },
};

//controller
tISM.controller = function() {
 this.token = m.prop("")
 this.keys = m.prop([])

 this.updateToken = function(token) {
  this.token(token)
  tISM.keys(this.token).then(this.keys)
 }.bind(this)

};

//view
tISM.view = function(ctrl) {
 return m("div"), [
  m("input", {
   oninput: m.withAttr("value", ctrl.updateToken)
  }),
  m("ol", ctrl.keys().map( function(key, index) {
   return m("li", key.Id, key.Name, key.CreationTime)
  })),
 ]

};


//initialize
m.mount(document.getElementById("app"), tISM);
```

Answer (score 0):

m.request() returns a deferred, not the value itself.  I have a snippet below that shows one way of getting the values out.  I explicitly replaced the m.request() with deferred calls under the hood, and a timeout rather than a post.

```js
//component
var tISM = {};


//model
tISM = { 
 Key: function(data) {
  this.Id = m.prop(data.Id);
  this.Name = m.prop(data.Name);
  this.CreationTime = m.prop(data.CreationTime);
 },

keys: function(token) {
  m.startComputation()
  var d = m.deferred();
  setTimeout(function() {
    d.resolve([1,2,3]);
    m.endComputation();
  }, 1000);
  return d.promise;
}
};

//controller
tISM.controller = function() {
 // when this controller is updated perform a new POST for data by calling message?
 var token = m.prop("xxx")

  var keys = m.prop([]);
  tISM.keys(this.token).then(keys)
  return {
token: token,
keys: keys
  }
 return { token, keys }
};

//view
tISM.view = function(ctrl) {
 return m("div"), [
  m("ol", ctrl.keys().map( function(key, index) {
   return m("li", key.Id, key.Name, key.CreationTime)
  })),
  m("input", {
   onchange: m.withAttr("value", ctrl.token)
  })
 ]
};



//initialize
m.mount(document.getElementById("app"), tISM);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mithril/0.2.5/mithril.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Mithril App</title>
    <script src="mithril.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```